# Random Shuffle Javascript to AMP Compliant

Tags: javascript, amp-html

Is there a way to convert this JavaScript Random Shuffle code in a table to be AMP compliant? (example stringId = table's Id)

```
<script>function swapRows(){var row=document.getElementById("stringId").rows;var rL=row.length;var tbody=row[0].parentNode;for(i=0;i<rL;i++){tbody.insertBefore(row[Math.ceil(Math.random()*(rL-1))],row[i]);}}swapRows()</script>
```

*It works great for me in regular HTML5 pages.

Comment: I know that `amp-script` accepts `document.getElementById("string")` and `.parentNode`. https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom/blob/master/web_compat_table.md  `amp-bind` accepts `Math.ceil` and `Math.random`. I guess I was looking for someone who has done something similar using both AMP components. I am also wondering if there is at way to implement a Fisher-Yates shuffle without using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You must mimic the functionality with your server side programming language (like PHP, Ruby, etc)

You can use the `amp-script` component to write JS code, but it is still [experimental](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/experimental/) and prone to unexpected errors which shouldn't be used in production.

That said, even if `amp-script` was fully functional, your code still wouldn't work, because it mutates the elements on page load, which is forbidden with custom JS in AMP. [You can only mutate elements with JS on user interaction in AMP.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYXkVOiz77I&t=1095s)